How to connect to the existing database through NGINX?
I have a project what I need to start with Docker. I've successfully created images and containers of Django, NGINX and postgreSQL, so the project starts correctly. I noticed that when I try to login to the admin panel, Django raises OperationalError at /admin/login/ connection to server at "database" (192.168.144.2), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied. Everything worked fine without nginx, but now I cannot access to the database. As I understand the problem, I need to change nginx.config, but I tried almost everything and still cannot figure this out. Seems like postgreSQL doesn't see my user maybe. My code snippet below.
uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]

wsgi-file = config/wsgi.py

strict = true  
 
socket = :8000  

protocol = http

master = true  

no-orphans = true   

die-on-term = true  

lazy-apps = true

processes = 4  

threads = 8   

enable-threads = true  

max-requests = 500

reload-on-rss = 1024
 
worker-reload-mercy = 60

harakiri = 60

harakiri-verbose = true

vacuum = true

post-buffering = 1048576

buffer-size = 65535

nginx.conf
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://django:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

    }
}

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine

RUN apk add postgresql-client build-base postgresql-dev linux-headers pcre-dev

WORKDIR /movies_admin

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

EXPOSE 8000

COPY movies_admin .

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8' 

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
    
    volumes:
      - "./movies_admin:/movies_admin"
    
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=database
      - POSTGRES_DB=movies_database
      - POSTGRES_USER=app
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123qwe
      - SECRET_KEY='django-insecure-8h%wg+drqmqjkw$8wm7#)#%*fb3b%(-e!-kbdth^#9u)23u!48'
    
    command:
      sh -c "uwsgi --ini /movies_admin/uwsgi.ini"
    
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:

    image: postgres:16

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=movies_database
      - POSTGRES_USER=app
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123qwe
    
    volumes:
      - $HOME/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django

components/database.py
import os

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', 'database'), # name of docker container with postgresql
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', 5432),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=public,content'
        }
    }
} 

P.S. I also think that idea might be in ports usage in docker-compose.yml, but as I read the dos, the best practice is to hide django and postgresql ports and connect only throught nginx.

In your database.py, you're looking for an environment variable DB_PASSWORD, but in the Compose file under django:, you're setting POSTGRES_PASSWORD.

I am voting to close this as a typo since the name of the environment variable your code expects and the name of the environment variable you specified don't match as described by David Maze.

Oh, I didn’t pay attention to variables, literally forgot about this. Thanks a lot.

Your problem appears to have nothing to do with Docker or NGINX. Read the error again: no password supplied - this means you are connecting just fine, but the database is not receiving a password
components/database.py is calling os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'), but where do you set this environment variable?
In docker-compose.yml, look at your django service environment variables. You are setting a variable named POSTGRES_PASSWORD, not DB_PASSWORD, which is what your django app is looking for.
Solution
Have the django service's components/database.py read in POSTGRES_PASSWORD rather than the current DB_PASSWORD.
